# Wait for button 2 to be clicked when button 1 is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, button, asynchronous, async-await

I have a button2 which has a lot of code to execute when is clicked.

At some point, I need to wait until a boolean is set to `true`, and that boolean is made `true` when button 1 is pressed. (I can't press button 1 while button2's code is running).

I've searched, but all I found is with methods running async. How can I wait for button 1 to be pressed?

Comment: Are you talking about a desktop application, with Winforms?

Comment: Yes, a Windows Form application.

Comment: so why can't you write code that will enable button2 once a particular condition has been met.. also from the sound of it why do you need to do any async / await .. it would help if you would show the code for the button1 click and button2 click.. since we can't see what you see on your end in regards to code.. I would highly suggest that you start putting break points in code and start stepping through your code and learn to debug..

Comment: @MethodMan The code is too long for me to show it. Button2 is pressed when, from a ListBox, it is selected a specific item, so I guess there is no condition to put. The ListBox is populated in button 1, a few instructions up from where I need to be pressed button2.

Comment: long code or not show what ever portion is relevant so you are saying that once you make a selection from a ListBox and Click on Button2.. then you want to wait for the process to finish before you can click on Button1..?? if so I do not know why it's so difficult for you to add the enable / disable code for Button1.Enabled = false until that process has finished.. post a scaled down version of both methods.. also if you are adding `TOO MUCH` code to a single button click.. then you need to break down the code into smaller methods ... if you don't show code nobody can help you ..

Comment: how is anyone supposed to help you if we can't see the code that you are working with.. come on now.. think about that for a sec..

Comment: You don't understand. The code is something like that:
bool x=false;
private button1()
{
..........
if(x==false)
{
populate list box
}
else
{
sendXmlRequestToSomeApi();
}}

private button2()
{
x=true;
}


I need after I populate the listbox, to wait to be pressed button1, and then to go to else hand to send the request.

Comment: Why do you need to wait to btn1 press?
what about something like this:
`btn1_click() {
    if (!populated) {
        populateList();
        populated = true;
    } else {
        callApi();
    }
}
btn2_click() {
    if (populated) {
        callApi();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution (may not be the most elegant):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Variable to store whether button one has been clicked or not
    private bool btnOneClicked = false;

    // ..

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When button one is clicked, execute the code that needs to run before waiting for your second button to be clicked
        LongCodeToExecuteFirst();
        // Set your variable to true to say that button one has been clicked
        btnOneClicked = true;
    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // First check if button one has been clicked
        if (btnOneClicked)
        {
            // If it has, execute the rest of the code that needed to be executed after button two was pressed
            LongCodeToExecuteSecond();
            // Reset our button one pressed variable to false
            btnOneClicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void LongCodeToExecuteFirst()
    {
        // Code to execute before button two is pressed
    }

    private void LongCodeToExecuteSecond()
    {
        // Code to execute after button two is pressed
    }
}
```